# Ajax does not show any functionality in Django

Tags: python, django, ajax

I want to display an error screen for a new user who wants to retrieve a user name already taken using Ajax, but the project continues to run as if Ajax did not exist and django gives its own error.

how can i fix this problem ?

Thanks for help :):):)

...................................................................

register.html

```
{% extends "layout.html"%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block body %}

<script>
    $("#id_username").change(function () {
      var username = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/validate_username/',
        data: {
          'username': username
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.is_taken) {
            alert("A user with this username already exists.");
          }
        }
      });

    });
  </script>

<body style = background-color:midnightblue;color:White;>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <h3>Register</h3>
    <hr style="background:white;">
     <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form|crispy}}
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class ="btn btn-danger">Register</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

{% endblock body %}
```

page source

```
<script>
    $("#id_username").change(function () {
      var username = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/validate_username/',
        data: {
          'username': username
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.is_taken) {
            alert("A user with this username already exists.");
          }
        }
      });

    });
  </script>

<div class=""> 
<input type="text" name="username" required class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_username">
</div>
```

views.py

```
def validate_username(request):
    username = request.GET.get('username')
    data = {
        'is_taken' :p User.objects.filter(username__iexact=username).exist()
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/',views.loginUser,name = "login"),
    path('register/',views.register,name = "register"),
    path('logout/',views.logoutUser,name = "logout"),
    path('panel/<str:username>',views.userPanel,name="userPanel"),
    path('ajax/validate_username/',views.validate_username,name="validate_username")
]
```

Comment: can u please tell me are you getting any error? while performing this ajax request. If u are using GET request i think then it should pass through url. Else change it to POST and check once.

Comment: @VaniPolnedi , i try with post method and request.is_ajax() and i didn't get a error. I saw just django error 'UNIQUE constraint failed: user_user.username'.